# Getting MM field extra in my date

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I am developing a small application,in which am fetching the data as **date**  in this format `yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss.MM` but in my data base date field has stored as in this format `yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss` can any one tell me that why am getting **MM** as extra thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MM` is the miscrosecond part of Datetime datatype.

Microsecond was introduced in Mysql version 5.6.4 .

The Microsecond part is introduced if during table creation datatype is specified as

```
DATETIME(fractional_part)
```

See [Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)

You should define date field as DATETIME(2) to get microseconds